# react-native Android sub projects compile deprecated

Tags: android, react-native

I have several dependencies on react-native Android libs in a project where I'm trying to upgrade gradle to the latest (v5 from v4). The most common issue I'm running into with these sub projects is `compile` being deprecated and replaced with `api` or `implementation`.

My first thought is to put in a PR for these projects but some look un-maintained and I might be better off forking them and maintaining the fork for my project.

Is there any alternatives to resolving this issue without forking these sub-projects? I had an issue with one dependency having a different build tools version and was able to resolve in my `build.gradle` like so:

```
subprojects {
  afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
            buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to accomplish via gradle/groovy scripts.